# How to keep minimum and maximum take O(1) time in a balanced binary search tree, without mucking about with pointers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The excise 3-7 in "Algorithm Design Manual" book says:

> Suppose you have access to a balanced dictionary data structure, which supports each of the operations search, insert, delete, minimum, maximum, successor, and predecessor in O(log n) time. Explain how to modify the insert and delete operations so they still take O(log n) but now minimum and maximum take O(1) time. (Hint: **think in terms of using the abstract dictionary operations, instead of mucking about with pointers and the like**.)

Without the hints, I think this question is fairly easy.

Here is my solution:

for the tree, I just maintain a pointer min always pointing to minimum, and another pointer max always pointing to maximum.

When inserting x, I just compare min.key with x.key, `if min.key > x.key, then min = x;` and also do this for max, if necessary.

When deleting x, `if min==x, then min = successor(x); if max==x, then max = predecessor(x);`

But the hint says I can't mucking about the pointers and the like. Does my solution muck about with pointers?

If we can't use extra points, how can I get O(1) for minimum and maximum?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is, your solution is the one ask for in the question, since you change the `insert` and `delete` operations, but keeping them at O(log n) because what you do is O(log n) of the old `insert`/`delete` plus O (log n) for either `successor` or `predecessor`, which stays at O(log n) in total. And you are not fiddling with pointers here, because you actually keep the `min` and `max` value.

Comment: @stryba, I thought so too. But need clarifications.

Comment: I'm not clear on the "mucking with pointers" part. My guess is you are not supposed to point to previous max/min values and rather use successor etc.

Comment: The point @stryba is trying to show is: You can just use on insert [after inserting]: `if (newVal < currMin.val) currMin = predessor(currMin)`, and similar idea to max. And on delete - the same idea, [before deleting]: `if (delVal == currMin.val) currMin = successor(currMin)` [and again, same idea for max]. This way, you can cache the min/max without playing with pointers - just using the tree's interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is the same one I would give - you're not messing with pointers, you're just storing the min/max values.

So, just be more confident :)

Comment: are you sure? I am just afraid one day an interviewer asks me this question, but I answered in a wrong way.

Comment: @Jackson: Again, **confidence** :) That is more important for an interview than your ability to solve silly algorithm puzzles, anyways

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve log(N) time for update/delete and constant time for getting the minimum / maximum value by using [Min-Max Heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap)

Comment: I don't think `delete` is intended to be restricted to the min and max, so in a Min-Max-Heap, `delete` would include an O(N) search.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get O(1) for both maximum and mininum.

Anyway, the book wants you to discover [binary heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) by yourself. Don't look at the link if you want to do it yourself. Only consider this hint: "The root of the tree always contains the min value" (or the max value if you want "maximum" to be O(1)).

Comment: the binary heaps are good hints. but the thing is that the question in the book really said "now minimum and maximum take O(1) time", if using heap, then it will be like what you said, we can't get O(1) for both at the same time. Are you sure about your hints?

Comment: Yeah, my hint only works for min or max, not both. I don't see you can  get both without changing your structure at all. O(1) means "in a fixed number of operations". It means both min and max should be near the top of the tree, which doesn't work if you want to keep O(log n) for insert/delete.

Comment: do you think your hints about this excise may be somehow wrong?

Comment: "The book is wrong" is probably not the answer. And yes, I could be wrong. What I'd do to answer the question 1/ explain how it would work for only max and only min 2/ explain or try to prove why I think it couldn't be done for both operations. The restrictions on successor/predecessor and insert/delete are strong, and don't give you much choice on what you can do without "mucking with pointers".

Comment: I think the hints given don't apply, since we are dealing with a balanced binary search tree not a heap.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two binary heaps: a min and a max heap. In each one you store half the elements and that way you can access both max and min in O(1) time. The min heap would contain the half with the smallest elements and the max heap the half with the larger elements. The insert/delete operations would all still be O(log n). When inserting a new element just check to which heap it should go.

Answer (score 0):

Store two values, the maximum and minimum. These need to be checked and potentially updated on every delete. If a the minimum is being deleted, call the successor, update the minimum and delete the old item. On insert, compare the new item to min/max, if it replaces either one update the min/max accordingly